# Tensorflow: running code on multiple nodes

Tags: tensorflow

```
import json
import tensorflow as tf

num_devices=3
with open('clusterspec.json', 'r') as f:
  clusterspec = json.load(f)

cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec(clusterspec)


a = tf.constant(3)
b = tf.constant(2)

for i in range(num_devices):
    with tf.device("/job:worker/task:%d"%i):

            if( i == 0):
                    x = tf.mul(a,b)
            if( i == 1):
                    y = tf.mul(a,b)
            if( i == 2):
                    z = tf.mul(a,b)


server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name="master", task_index=0)
with tf.Session(server.target) as sess:
  print "here"
  print(sess.run([x,y,z]))
```

Could someone please suggest a better way to run this simple example on multiple machines. I don't want to have three different tensors `x`, `y`, and `z`. Instead, I want only a single tensor, and not use the branching within the graph at all.

Comment: I don't understand why a '-1' appears next to this post.

Comment: Yes. I'm also looking to understand this. I hope you get an answer. +1

Comment: I don't understand what this tries to do; this should fail with some of x,y,z being undefined python variables at the `sess.run` line.